# Cannot get parameters to controller using event listener in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I am currently using the Symfony2 event listener to change the controller to a different one based on a users authentication status. I get the listener to set the new controller but it is instantiated without the container parameter (i.e. $this->container returns null).

Is there anyway to pass the container on to the controller I am changing to?

```
class AuthenticationListener
{
  public function onController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
  {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if (!$session->has('authenticated') || $session->get('authenticated') === false)
    {
      $controller = $event->getController();

      if (!($controller[0] instanceof AuthenticateController) && !($controller[0] instanceof ExceptionController))
      {
        $event->setController(array(new AuthenticateController(), 'loginAction'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container is not set, when you create the controller automatically. Call setContainer after constructing the controller. Afterwards you can pass it to the event.

Comment: I ended up just injecting the container service into my listener in the config.yml, then passing the container to my controller in its constructor to make it available to my actions within the controller.

Answer (score -1):

In this case AuthenticationListener its just a class

if you want to use $this->container in this class you must do like this:

```
class BeforeControllerListener extends ContainerAware
{
...
}
```

and in config.yml

```
core.listener.before_controller:
    class: App\YourBundle\EventListener\YourListener
    tags: [ {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController}]
    calls:
        - [ setContainer,[ @service_container ]]
```